# How many people ever lived having a certain profession?

Tags: historical, demographics

Is there any data on how many

- politicians(including feudal lords)
- clergy (priests, imams, monks ...)
- scientists(whatever that may be called in ancient cultures)
- ...

have ever lived on earth? *(or in the universe :)*